# How to efficiently replace german umlauts in C++?

Tags: c++, string

Assume that I get a few hundred lines of text as a string (C++) from an API, and sprinkled into that data are german umlauts, such as ä or ö, which need to be replaced with ae and oe.
I'm familiar with encoding (well, I've read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and solving the problem was trivial (basically, searching through the string, removing the char and adding 2 others instead).

However, I do not know enough about C++ to do this fast. I've just stumbled upon StringBuilder (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/647856/4350-Performance-Improvement-with-the-StringBuilde), which improved speed a lot, but I was curious if there are any better or smarter ways to do this?

Comment: With utf8 it is easier: ä, ö and ü are two-byte long, as are ae oe and ue.

Comment: Btw, I'm asking this question to actually learn something about C++ - (I learned a lot from the linked Stringbuilder article) - my code is fast enough for my purposes :-)

Comment: What is the encoding of the input string? As other responses indicate, the conversion strategy is governed by the encoding involved.
If you could indicate this, I'm sure you'll get some more pointers...

Comment: @BirgitP.: `StringBuilder` is useless in C++... you just have to use `std::string` properly in the first place. The real question, however, is what the encoding of your string is. Could you point to use how the letters with umlauts and the letters with a trailing `e` are represented at byte level ?

Comment: @AlexandreC. : they're 2 bytes unless they're three: ä can also be `0x61 0xCC 0x88`. In the latter case, it is easy to remove the umlaut: just delete the CC 88.

Answer (score 4):

If you must improve efficiency on such small scale, consider doing the replacement in two phases:

- The first phase calculates the number of characters in the result after the replacement. Go through the string, and add `1` to the count for each normal character; for characters such as  ä or ö, add `2`.
- At this point, you have enough information to allocate the string for the result. Make a string of the length that you counted in the first phase.
- The second phase performs the actual replacement: go through the string again, copying the regular characters, and replacing umlauted ones with their corresponding pairs.

Comment: (Additional) It can be done in a single buffer. Enlarge the original buffer, and copy from last to first character. A simple loop, really.

Answer (score 2):

When it is encoded in UTF-8, the german umlauts are all two-byte values in unicode, and so are their replacements like `ae` or `oe`. So when you use a char[] instead of a string, you wouldn't have to reallocate any memory and could just replace the bytes while iterating the char[].

Comment: The problem is that I'm using an API provided by someone else, but I'll try to see if it performs better if I convert twice.

Comment: @BirgitP. `std::string.c_str()` is a constant-time operation and returns a pointer to the internal buffer used by the std::string. So there isn't any overhead and you don't have to convert it back.

Comment: This is only true if “unicode” here refers to UTF-8. If it is UTF-16, the byte count for “ö” and “oe” is different. If it is latin1 it is trivial again.

Comment: @Philipp Isn't `std::string.c_str()` a `const` function returning a `const char*`? If so, you would need to cast away constness to do what you suggest. I hope I'm wrong and there is also a non-const variant...

Comment: @cmaster You can use [``std::string::front()``](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/front) for that

Comment: @JonasWielicki Thank you, I forgot about UTF-16. I updated my answer.

Comment: @JonasWielicki Ah, thank you. So there's now six different methods in C++11 to get the address of the first character: `begin()`, `cbegin()`, `operator[]`, `front()`, `c_str()` and `data()`. Impressive...

Comment: @cmaster: Only 2 of those return an address (.data and .c_str), and that's a backwards compatibility thing. Also, you forgot `.rend()`.

Comment: @MSalters I didn't use the term 'address' instead of 'pointer' without thought: I know that C++ programmers don't like to talk about pointers, but I wanted to talk about the underlying mechanic. Now, `begin()` and `cbegin()` return iterators on the language level, but that's (hopefully) a plain old pointer under the hood. I excluded `rend()` on purpose, because that one can't return a plain old pointer due to the reverse semantic. `operator[]` and `front()` both return a `char&`, which is definitely a plain old pointer under the hood. So I count six functions returning this address.

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly the sort of information I've been looking for!